# Extra indexes folders created in SOLR

Tags: solr, solr4

While replicating index to slave servers, extra indexes folders have been created with date time stamp appended to folder names. 
Can anyone tell

1. what exactly is the issue?
2. Is it really issue?
3. How it can be
       resolved?

Comment: I think it could be a configuration issue with solr.xml file, make sure that instanceDir is correct in all cores, and that the folder exists

Answer (score 0):

Solr creates indexes in the form of multiple files on the server. There is no issue with it. Also replication may create its own separate files for internal use. Your search will work without any problem.